# Reading yaml file which is outside of Jar inside a docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to read a YAML file outside of the jar in my springboot project. But the `targetStream` always returns null value. I'm running this in a docker container so the required file that I needs to read resides in the same folder `config/keys.yaml`.

When the container is running, I need to fetch values from keys.yaml file.

This is what I have tried so far.

**EDITED**

I am running this docker image inside AWS ECR container with help of the ECS task. in that container, I have configured an EFS volume to store some configurations which fetch from another source. So Each time this container starts it stores a YAML file inside the `app/config` file location. So I need to find a way to read that file from that location and do some action in a java class.

**Test.java**

```
    String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "config"+File.separator+"keys.yaml";
    LOGGER.info("file Path "+ filePath);
    File initialFile = new File(filePath);

    try (InputStream targetStream = Files.newInputStream(initialFile.toPath());) {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        HashMap<String,String> yamlMap = yaml.load(targetStream);
```

**DockerFile**

```
#pull base image
FROM java:8-jre

COPY target/test.jar /app/

EXPOSE 80 3306

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "app/test.jar"]
```

Here is the structure of the folder

```
app:
  test.jar
  config:
      keys.yaml
```

Comment: Your image only contains the JRE and the jar file.  If you need access to the configuration file you need to `COPY` it into your image, or make it available via a bind mount (or build it into your jar file and handle it as a Java resource).

Comment: yeah. I have a mount point configured inside the container app/config path. that's why I have a requirement to fetch data from that location to my jar file

Comment: That seems like a key detail that would be part of a [mcve]; can you [edit] the question to include the details of how you're starting the container?

Comment: Have you tested this same setup locally, using a local bind mount? I would get this working locally first before attempting the ECS/EFS deployment which may have all kinds of additional network and IAM settings issues you would need to work through.

Comment: yeah I tried this locally also. still couldn't find a way to read a file. it works fine in ECS/ECR when it hard coded inside. I tried by putting that configuration file inside spring resource folder. what I couldn't figure out is how to read the file when file is outside the jar